# Metainfomation that is more important than the infomation itself

Tags: security

For example: an officer is theoritically allowed to read a report if he ask, but he isn't allowed to know about the existence or the secret level of that report.

Can the secret level of an infomation be lower than the infomation about its secret level? What specific situation can make it so? What infomation about infomation maybe more important than the infomation itself?

Comment: This information is Need to know.

Comment: Maybe the source of the information is confidential while the information itself isn't.

Comment: I fail to see how this question relates to WorldBuilding. It looks like it would be better on a specialised site, maybe [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). And coming up with specific situations is something that should be done by the author, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: If you would focus your questions, you could receive better answers for your world.

Comment: Sometimes individual instances aren't important, but taken in aggregate they show patterns -- for instance, that someone in the pentago ordered a pepperoni pizza isn't important.  But that orders went up significantly in a rather short period of 1993 is.  (as it was a week before the start of the first Gulf War).  Likewise, a video of an endangered animal might not be important ... but enough of them w/ timestamps and geolocation, and you have a treasure trove for poachers.

Comment: In addition to the great real-life security examples given in the answer, I also wanted to point out that we see examples of this in religions as well.  the gnostic religions had two levels.  Anyone was permitted to know the "outer mystery," which was a story -- the information itself.  If you were invited into the inner circle, you were permitted to learn the "inner mystery" which explained how the story should be interpreted -- the metadata.

Comment: I think this question would have a better match on the http://security.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are times when some of the meta-information in a security report is more important than the report data itself.

For example, the Allies went to great lengths to disguise the fact that they had broken the German [Enigma machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptanalysis_of_the_Enigma#German_suspicions). For the war efforts, knowing whether or not Enigma was hacked was far more important than any one message, and probably more important than entire days' worth of messages.

Or in today's terms, many articles have pointed out that one of the concerns over Trump's alleged leak of code-word level secrets to Russia isn't so much the secrets he gave them, but what those secrets tell Russia about how those secrets were collected and by whom.

And a third example of meta-data vs. data is the [NSA wiretap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_warrantless_surveillance_(2001%E2%80%9307)) exposed by Snow. The system, as explained by his leaks through various media sources, provided details such as who contacted whom, when, how often, by what means, and such. This lets their system build a web of interconnections that hints at who might be working with whom or who knows whom. All of those links are technically metadata.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach to hide information is to dilute it among a huge amount of false information.

Imagine for example of having the schematic of a new weapon: instead of concealing it, one can put it in a folder with thousands (or more) of other similar but wrong schematics.

The metainformation on which schematic is the correct one would then be more important than a single schematic.

Something similar was done in WW2: when the German occupied Netherlands and tried to use Philips factory to manufacture for their equipement, the management, instead of hiding the schematics simply corrupted them making them unusable for producing functioning equipments, and kept that information secret.

Answer (score 2):

There is a legal ruling in the UK called a Superinjuction [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-injunctions_in_English_law)

An example would be a footballer caught in a scandal; in this case the metadata is the fact that a court case is going on, which is deemed more important than the actual contents of the case. Therefore even the *existence* of the case cannot be reported on. It makes some sort of sense, because people tend to believe that something has happened as soon as a court case starts.

(This is highly dubious from a free speech perspective, obviously)

Answer (score 2):

The only situation I can imagine where it's okay to inform others of the content of a message and not tell them about the message would be in the journalism industry. Specifically, a journalist trying to provide information to his/her readers while also protecting a source. (Also, from [Andrew's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/81129/6986), courts in the UK.)

> Journalist: "Sources say the information was classified at the highest level."
>
> Person: "Who are your sources?"
>
> Journalist: "I can't tell you that."

With classification levels, it's the content of the information that is being protected. Any system that produces information generates that information at the highest classification level available to the system. A person may be allowed to know the information exists, but without both a Need to Know and the appropriate clearance, that person isn't allowed to see the information.

Of course, this being worldbuilding, you can always define your own classification system with the security level you have in mind.